# Customizing three-way interaction in R package sjplot plot_model using shapes and themes

Tags: r, ggplot2, sjplot

I want my three-way interaction  to look as closely as possible to my two-way interaction plot. Basically the same, just with two facets (called panels in my example). I would love to continue to use `sjplot` with `plot_model`. However, as soon as I pass any aesthetic argument to the threewayplot I get "Error in plot_model(threeway, type = "int", title = "The threeway plot that does not work",  :
non-numeric argument to binary operator". And when I pass any of the theme parts it is just NULL.

Any ideas for any way to solve this, please?

So, I created the following MWE:

```
library(sjPlot)
library(ggplot)


data("mtcars")

mydf <- mtcars



mydf$high <- ifelse(mydf$mpg >= 20, 1, 0)
mydf$gear <- as.factor(mydf$gear)
mydf$am <- as.factor(mydf$am)

twoway <- glm(high ~  am*gear, data = mydf, family = "binomial")


plot_model(twoway, type = "int", title = "My fancy twoway plot", show.legend = TRUE, 
           transform = "plogis", show.values = TRUE,
           dot.size = 5, line.size = 1.5, value.offset = 0, 
           colors = c( "#333333",  "#666666","black")) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c( 15,16, 17)) +
  aes(color=group, shape = group) + 
  labs(shape = "Cool group", color = "Cool group")+
  theme_sjplot() + 
  theme(strip.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "bottom"
  )

## Threeway
mydf$panelvar <- ifelse(mydf$carb > 3,  "Panel Left", "Panel Right")
mydf$panelvar  <- as.factor(mydf$panelvar)


threeway <- glm(high ~  panelvar*gear*am, data = mydf, family = "binomial")


plot_model(threeway, type = "int", title = "My sad threeway plot which works", show.legend = TRUE, 
           transform = "plogis", show.values = TRUE,
           dot.size = 5, line.size = 1.5, value.offset = 0, 
           colors = c( "#333333",  "#666666","black"))



plot_model(threeway, type = "int", title = "The threeway plot that does not work", show.legend = TRUE, 
           transform = "plogis", show.values = TRUE,
           dot.size = 5, line.size = 1.5, value.offset = 0, 
           colors = c( "#333333",  "#666666","black"))+
  scale_shape_manual(values = c( 15,16, 17)) +
  aes(color=group, shape = group) + 
  labs(shape = "Cool group", color = "Cool group") +
  theme_sjplot() + 
  theme(strip.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "bottom"
  )
```

Thanks in advance!